# why does my class not recognize my method?

Tags: java, methods, return, boolean

I'm really sorry if this is stupid, but I've tried lots of different things and and it may be that I've sort of not recognized the answer I was looking for while looking through lots of questions and answers, but I'm only a beginner, so I may not have understood it (yet).

I've tried to make boolean method that determines whether a number is a prime number or not and to use it within my main class. But when trying to compile everything, I always get the error "cannot find symbol", and by symbol it means the name of my method. :( I just don't know what to do to employ my method in my main class. Did I forget to return something? If so, what?
Please help me.

```
public class PrimeNumber {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 1234;
    if (isPrimeNumber == true) {
        System.out.println("You won!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, nah.");
    }
}

static boolean isPrimeNumber(int number) {
    int d = 2;
    int counter = 0;
    while (d < number/2) {  
        if (number % d == 0) {
            counter = counter + 1;
            d++;
        } else {
            d++;
        }
    }
    if (counter >= 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Sorry if something is unclear and thank you very much in advance, I appreciate you help! :)

Comment: You're missing the parentheses and parameter on the method call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
isPrimeNumber == true
```

you need to write

```
isPrimeNumber(number)
```

`isPrimeNumber` is a method, not a variable, and you must call methods with parentheses and arguments.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the method (you are missing **()** after the methods name and the integer parameter....

and since the method return boolean you can gte rid off the `== true` part

```
if (isPrimeNumber(number)) {
```

or

```
if (isPrimeNumber(123)) {
```